# Writing chinese character to jexcelapi

Tags: java, jexcelapi

I have a problem on how to write chinese character to jexcel.

here is my code..

nameChinese is taken from mysql database..

```
public String getNameChinese(String nameChinese)
{
String strNameChinese = "";

        try
        {
            strNameChinese = new String(nameChinese.getBytes("utf-8"), "iso-8859-1");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            return strNameChinese;
        }
    }// getNameChinese()
```

Excel.java

```
Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(templatePath)); 
WritableWorkbook copy = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File(resultPath + resultFileName), workbook); 

WritableSheet sheet = copy.getSheet(0);

Label nameLabel = new Label(1, currentIndex, getNameChinese(), normalAllSideWarpFormat);
sheet.addCell(nameLabel);

copy.write();
copy.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about jExcelAPI, but I suspect part of your problem is your handling of your Strings...

A String in Java has an internal representation of UTF-16. The transformation you're doing in your getNameChinese method would destroy the display of any character outside of US-ASCII. (and Chinese characters are!).

I'll walk through your code so that I can illustrate this issue. In the meantime, for the sake of argument, I'm assuming that nameChinese is being properly stored and retrieved from your MySQL database. (But this is another very easy source of character encoding problems).

1. Let us assume that nameChinese="[汉](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/6c49/index.htm)"
2. `nameChinese.getBytes("UTF-8")` yields an array of 3 bytes `0xE6,0xB1,0x89`
3. This array of bytes intrepreted as [ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) yields the characters "æ±?" (the last one is not actually the printable character ?, but rather a control character).

What happens if you put the string you retrieved from the database directly into the jExcelAPI?